# Get MS Booking Attributes in Calendar Event

Tags: rest

We are trying to get attributes from MS Booking in the Outlook Calendar event so we can work with them in our webapp.

We see the Booking attributes using Graph Beta explorer (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/XXXX/appointments).
We have extended the calendar event schema with some custom fields we want to populate them

It would be great if the Booking attributes passed to the calendar event (not as text in the body)
We have looked at the Booking and the Event JSON and have not identified how these are linked.

See the image that is doing a side by side comparison of the Booking and Even JSON

[Side by side json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZED35.png)

Comment: Follow up question - how do we find the corresponding Calendar Event from the Booking Appointment?

Answer (score 0):

BookingItem is a CalenderItem internally. Hence you can use the calendar graph APIs to access the calendar specific properties of a bookingItem.

Please request for "Calendars.Read/Calenders.ReadWrite" scopes for the OAuth token and use the query in the following format to list all events of a Booking Calender.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users//calendar/events

Or the following to get individual properties of a booking item.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users//calendar/events/

Adding the Calendar graph doc for your information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http